# Loading image from object NSData into UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsdata

I have an object named `http` that retrieves a string from a php script which is a URL to an image.

In the class, I load it into an NSData member like this:

```
profileImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:result]];
```

`result` is the URL string, already checked.

And to load it up in my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
NSLog(@"appeared");
http = [[HTTP alloc] init];
[http getProfileImage:[SignInViewController getUsernameString]];
NSLog(@"data: %@",http.profileImageData);
profileImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:http.profileImageData];
}
```

I get the error:

```
2012-03-01 11:03:16.865 Träffa[5574:f803] data: (null)
2012-03-01 11:03:16.878 Träffa[5574:f803] Error receiving response: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x6b7c840 {NSUnderlyingError=0x6b7c2c0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

Why is this returning null?

Edit: I narrowed the problem down to this:

```
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        profileImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:result]];
        NSLog(@"%@",profileImageData);
```

The first NSLog returns with the address, the second one on the NSData returns null. Am I writing this properly?

Comment: since you are recieving no data and get a NSURLErrorDomain Code, first thing you should check is youre url.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to trim the URL string even though it looked like it would be fine

```
result = [result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```